# Listar socios de un determinado cursillo

Tags: php, sql

Muy buenas tengo una base de datos en la que tengo que listar por pantalla los socios apuntados a un determinado cursillo cuando pinche en el enlace del cursillo correspondiente. El fallo viene al pasar por parámetro el id del curso (codcurso) correspondiente para que solo me muestre los socios apuntados a ese cursillo.

```
<?php

include ("conexion.php");

$registro=$_REQUEST['codcurso'];

$sql="SELECT cursillos.codcurso, cursillos.nombre as cnombre, 
socios.nombre as snombre from cursillos inner join socios on 
cursillos.codcurso=socios.codcurso order by cursillos.nombre where 
cursillos.codcurso='$registro'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    echo "<h2><center>CURSOS</center></h2>
 <table border='1' style='margin: 0 auto;'>
 <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>CÓDIGO CURSO</th>
        <th>NOMBRE</th>
        <th>NOMBRE SOCIO</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

       echo'
    <tr>
        <td><center>'.$row["codcurso"].'</center></td>
        <td><center>'.$row["cnombre"].'</center></td>
        <td><center>'.$row["snombre"].'</center></td></tr>';


}
} else {
echo "0 resultados";
}
echo "</table></div>";
echo '<a href="consultaCursos.php">Volver al listado</a>';
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: ¿Entonces tu problema está en esta línea? `$registro=$_REQUEST['codcurso'];`, ¿o es la query? ¿o después?

Comment: el problema esta en el where cursillos.codcurso='$registro', si yo quito esa parte, es decir sin where, me muestra todos los cursillos con sus correspondientes socios, pero quiero que solo me muestre los socios del cursillo que he seleccionado

Comment: Cuál es el valor de `$registro`? La variable `$sql` tiene el valor que esperas?

Comment: si, el valor de $registro es la variable del campo codcurso de la tabla SQL. Ya lo tengo resuelto, el fallo estaba en la clausula where, estaba detrás de order by que es siempre la última. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

El error estaba en la consulta SQL, la claúsula where estaba detras del order by,

La claúsula order by es siempre la útlima

```
$sql="SELECT cursillos.codcurso, cursillos.nombre as cnombre, socios.nombre as 
snombre from cursillos inner join socios on cursillos.codcurso=socios.codcurso 
where cursillos.codcurso='$registro' order by cursillos.nombre";
```

Comment: Duh! Claro jajaja, frente a nuestros ojos... 

Comment: Veo que ya lo has solucinado, ! Pero por favor lee [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php) El usar la variable `$registro` dentro de la misma select de esa forma es muy peligroso.

Comment: Gracias por la info! 